# How to reset the OrbitControls and when to use the update method?

Tags: three.js

I want to reset my camera which has an active damping. I've tried different ways but I don't know if they are correct.

The goal is to stop the damping and set the initial position of the camera and then activate the damping again. I want to avoid that the model/camera is rotating a bit after I reset the controls with a button. I would do it like this:

```js
controls.enableDamping = false;
controls.update();
camera.position.set( 10, 13, 10 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.update();
```

My rendering function is called by a EventListener:

```js
controls.addEventListener( "change", requestRenderer );
```

And the render function:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true } );       

let renderRequested = false;        

function render( time ) {           
    time *= 0.001;                  
    renderRequested = false;
    resizeRenderer( renderer, camera );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function requestRenderer() {
   if( !renderRequested ) {
       renderRequested = true;
       requestAnimationFrame( render );
   }
}
```

This works pretty well. The question is if this is the correct way and when do I have to update the controls? I think the first update is necessary to tell the controls that the damping isn't active anymore (but what does the update do?) and I think, that I don't need the second update.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like you don't need the second update. You aren't changing a *key* property about the controls, in your `render()` loop:

```js
controls.update();
```

Which covers every other case.

Comment: And why do I need the first one? In the three.js docs they say: "Update the controls. Must be called after any manual changes to the camera's transform, or in the update loop if .autoRotate or .enableDamping are set." So (de-)activating the damping does change the cameras transform?

Comment: @stoex, yes, but it looks like your render loop isn't always being called?

Comment: yes. I'm rendering on demand with the help of event-listeners like it is shown here: https://threejs.org/manual/#en/rendering-on-demand

Comment: You should create another `render()` loop that always runs and put `controls.update()` inside of that.

Comment: is there a special reason for this?

Comment: It is generally a good practice to *not* interrupt the flow of the `render()` loop.